# Cycles volume render renders as bounding box

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

hello im trying to render out a volume in cycles it was working fine in eevee but when i switch to cycles it just renders out as the entire box surrounding the volume, i used mesh to volume modifier if that helps, thanks!

[image: The weird thing]

Comment: As far as I know, there is no "Mesh to Volume" Modifier - did you mean something else?

Comment: if you add a volume empty and go to modifiers youll find one that says mesh to volume where you can eye drop a object and the volume should match the objects bounds

Comment: Ahhh - a volume empty - something I think I can say I've never used before - strange - normally EEVEE is the renderer that is guilty of showing a volume as a bounding box - not Cycles.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Which version of Blender?  Can you post the material-to-volume settings and any material settings you have for the volume?  Or better yet, add a blend file to your question that shows the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: i finally figured out that all i had to do was just completely remove materials from it, it made the problem go away